# swing jpopupmenu and jpanel is displaying a shadow

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I have a problem with jcomponent menu. The menu is working fine but when the menu is closing into the parent panel remains a shadow ( the grey color) with the size of the jpopup menu.
I have to mention that the jpanel that is the parent of the jpopup menu has the color mentioned above but has the transparency set to 25%.

Comment: It is a swing application

Answer (score 1):

> I have to mention that the jpanel that is the parent of the jpopup menu has the color mentioned above but has the transparency set to 25%.

See [Background With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=background%20with%20transparency) for the probable problem along with a couple of solutions.